# Why add a Foreign Key property to Entities in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

For the Entity below

```
class Entity
{
   public AnotherEntity AT { get; set; }
}
```

Many times I see people building model in this way

```
class Entity
{
   public AnotherEntity AT { get; set; }

   public int AT_Id { get; set; }
}
```

What is the use of this foreign key property? I can even see that Julie Lehrman recommend going this way. Why don't I just use `Entity.AT.Id` to access and update the model.

Comment: Because in the DB the table will have the foreign key, not the entire object and you might only want data from that table and not the other one, including the foreign key.

Comment: Below link has description why foreign keys are important 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Exposing a FK is optional. You can work with just navigation properties if desired (EF will create a FK in the database though). It can make certain updates easier where you know the value already exists.

Comment: The idea here is called **Referential Integrity**